# Windows server compute engine gives enable billing error

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have a free tier version of GCP and I am trying to provision Windows server with basic configuration.
It gives an error asking me about enabling the billing for the account.
I have checked the billing account details and the billing is enabled.
What am I missing here? I am unable to provision windows server on Google compute engine.

Comment: Did you wait 12 hours after enabling billing?

Answer (score 0):

It is not enough to have billing enabled. Since Windows servers aren't included in the free tier, you have to upgrade your account to a paid account in order to use them. If you still have credits from the free trial, those will be used for anything which is covered by the free tier, but you will be charged real money for anything which isn't (like Windows servers, for example).

Comment: As per [link](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier?hl=en#free-trial), under the Program coverage you can see that it's not possible to create Windows Server.

Comment: But that page says: "When using Windows-based images, you must wait 12 hours after enabling billing before you can create a Windows-based image, at which point you can apply your free trial credits."

Comment: Before that it says: _"Your free trial credit applies to all Google Cloud resources, with the following exceptions: (...) You can't create VM instances that are based on Windows Server images"_. To me, this means that you can supply a custom Windows image (importing from a local VM for example), which is not a server, but you can't use Windows Server images with the free tier.